# Python2.7 appending in list of list

Tags: python

I was trying to work with a list of lists, and want to take one of the elements in a list of list, work with it, and then append that to another list.

I found out that `.append()` had behaviour that I didn't expect:

```
def li_of_li_test (li):
    l = li[0]
    l.append(0)
    return li
```

The function should just return `li`, but instead...

```
print li_of_li_test ([[1,2,3],[4,5]])
```

Returns:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 0], [4, 5]]
```

What could I do to make it return

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5]]
```

Comment: Don't append `0` to the list? I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: You intentionally `append` a `0` to the first sub-`list` with `l = li[0]; l.append(0)`, then you're surprised when you get a new `0` in there? Why would you expect the value to remain unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

In python value is passed by reference. And the list is a variable structure.

```
from copy import deepcopy

def li_of_li_test (li):
    l = deepcopy(li[0])
    l.append(0)
    return li

print li_of_li_test ([[1,2,3],[4,5]])

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: Well, the problem here would be a misunderstanding of what `l = li[0]` does, not argument passing; after all, the value being printed is the value returned by the function, and even with pass-by-value semantics, that wouldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming in real code, this:

```
def li_of_li_test (li):
    l = li[0]
    l.append(0)
    return li
```

would be trying to leave the `li` argument unmodified, but take the first sub-`list` in `li`, and put a modified copy in some other `list`. You thought that `l = li[0]` would make a new copy of that sub-`list` to work with, but that's not what it does; it just makes `l` another reference to the same `list` stored in `li[0]`. If you want to copy the `list`, a simple shallow copy can be achieved with:

```
l = li[0][:]  # [:] is a complete slice of the sublist, a shallow copy
```

or you can with more work deep copy the components of the `list`, not just the `list` structure with:

```
import copy

l = copy.deepcopy(li[0])
```

Either way, simple `append`s and the like to `l` won't affect `li` anymore.

If you need to make many mutations to different sublists, `deepcopy`ing `li` as a whole may make sense; you'd do it once up front, and not need to worry about destructively mutating `li` after that.

Answer (score 0):

The following can solve your problem:

```
def li_of_li_test (li):
    l = li[:]
    l = list(li[0])
    l.append(0)
    return li
```